# required application for bar-code reader and logs generators  

Tags: logging, barcode, barcode-scanner, time-tracking

I'm looking for an application that logs barcodes and current time into a notepad or something that can easily be uploaded to a database.

For example: A user swipes his ID, then the application will record the barcode and time the user swiped,.. basically an employee time tracker.

I created a web based system but it takes a bit long and the users usually swipe multiple times really fast. Is there any application like that?, or can anyone suggest a programming/scripting language to make one?

Comment: The key point is finding out the weak link. It's the barcode reading part that slows down the process, or it's because of the log generation? If the latter, I believe you can optimize your source code as suggested by Johan. If it's the barcode reader, it depends on the tool you are using. The company I'm working for also provides  Barcode Reader SDK. You can try the demo to check out the performance. http://www.dynamsoft.com/Demo/DWTPlus/online_demo_scan_OCRBarcode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you know a bit of PHP, the following could easily be done with the following code:

```
while(true)
{
    $line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    echo 'Recorded ' . $line . ' to database' . "\n\n";
}
```

Just start the script from command line, I assume that the barcode scanner works just like a keyboard, it enters the numbers and presses enter.

Comment: You would save the scirpt as log.php, and run it from command line using:
    php log.php
Assuming you have PHP CLI installed.
Loggin to db could be done with:
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO logs (code, time) VALUES("' . mysql_real_escape_string($line) . '", "'. time() . ');